# How do I get an object (font style, font size, color, borders, lines, cell size) from excel using C#?

Tags: c#, excel

How do I get an object (font style, font size, color, borders, lines, cell size) from excel using C#?

Comment: it's for our thesis, and we are using Visual Studio. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to look Flexcel. By using that .Dll it will be piece of cake for you.

Thanks

Comment: i already looked for flexcel but seems to be difficult to understand and i think i should buy it, would you mind guiding me about flexcel? :)

Comment: Yes sure. No problem. I am playing with it from almost 2 years :)